# All workflows fail to start in a single subsite

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-manager

All the workflows in this specific subsite will not run, automatically or manually.  Initiator = Anonymous and Internal Status = Not Started.  I tested a couple other site collection workflows and they run without issue.

I created a new list and new, basic workflow in the problem subsite and the same thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Real strange that all the workflows in a subsite wouldn't work.  I would have expected all workflows everywhere or the workflows for a specific list to not work.  After the weekend, they seem to be working so maybe some IIS application pool recycling kicked it in the pants?